# I am receiving Undefined index errors

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create an administration panel on my site. I want to restrict access to people who don't have admin_privilege set to 1 in the database. I am fairly new to PHP and MySQL so I am unsure of where to start or how to fix this issue.

This is in my admin/index.php file.

```
    if ($_SESSION['admin_privilege'] == 1) {
        if ($_SESSION['admin_privilege'] == 'Administrator') {
            //Do nothing
        }
    } else {
        echo "You don't have permission to access this page.";
    }
```

And this is the error I'm receiving when I go to admin/index.php

```
Notice: Undefined index: admin_privilege in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\index.php on line 11
You don't have permission to access this page.
```

My admin_privileged is set to 1 in the database.

Comment: plz show us page that you use to set sessions

Comment: Try `if ( isset($_SESSION['admin_privilege']) && $_SESSION['admin_privilege'] == 1)`

Comment: @NipunTharuksha but is not set ($_SESSION['admin_privilege']) code go in `echo "You don't have permission to access this page."`

Comment: Yeah true I meant that this dosent good for all the requireents. I know your comment is correct. Sorry I didnt try to demotivate you